# System.IndexOutOfRangeException c#

Tags: c#, string

somehow, this seemed to work a few years back ;)
or am i missing someting?

help would be appriciated
thx in advance.

```
else if (recStatus == 3)         
{
            ((TextBox)rref[1]).Text = read;

            //string readData = read;
            string[] readData = read.Split(new Char[] { ',' });


            //string[] readdata = read.Split(',');
            txtType.Text = readData[0];
            txtSerno.Text = readData[1]
            txtFirmware.Text = readData[2] + "." + readData[3];
}
```

Comment: you readDate may contain only one comma and when getting array [1] or [2] or [3] it would not find it

Comment: What is your question? what is rref? which line throws the error?

Comment: On which line is that exception thrown?

Comment: Which line does it through the error?

Comment: well not that i would want to disturb you, but you think you could stop 1 minute and read what the code does? You are accesing and array index that does not exist.

Comment: What is _the question_ by the way?

Comment: txtType.Text = readData[0]; is the line where i get the error...

Comment: then there is no comma in your reaData variable. send us the data as well

Comment: the question is .. how to get rid of the error ;)

Comment: put commas in your string

Comment: output is A401,192,2,8

Comment: @none see my answer below

Comment: This can easily be resolved by using Visual Studio and debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

System.IndexOutOfRangeException in this code means that readData have less then 4 value,

you can know the number of element by

```
string[] readData = read.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
MessageBox.Show(readData.Length.ToString()); //you will found it less then 4
```

Comment: when i use the code it tells me the int can't be converted to a string

Answer (score 0):

I just run your sample and got no errors in console app (**it might be because of the text you are passing put a debugger and see what is actual text on ((TextBox)rref[1]).Text**  ):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string read = "A401,192,2,8" ;

            string[] readData = read.Split(new Char[] { ',' });


            //string[] readdata = read.Split(',');
            string a = readData[0];
            string b = readData[1] + "." + readData[2];
            string c = readData[3];

            Console.WriteLine(a + b + c);
        }
    }
```

result :

```
A401192.28
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: sorry i had the fields numbered wrong...
but anyways, even correctly, i get the same result as you.

Comment: as i said try to put break point on this line ((TextBox)rref[1]).Text  and post the result

Comment: i solved the problem... thank you all anyways... i just needed to initialize my button data before running the code from above